# error in iterating maps to get input

Tags: c++

In chess, each type of coin has some weight. Given the name of the coin and weight for the coin, write a C++ code to print the name of the coins in ascending order of their weight. Assume that weight of each coin is unique.
I want to use map

My codes is here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,i=0;
    char name;
    int weight;
    cin>>n;

    class std::map<char,int> coins;
    while(i<n)
    {
              i++;
              cin>>name;
              cin>>weight;
              coins[name]=weight;
              }
    coins.sort(coins.begin(),coins.end(),weight);
    while(i<n){
               i++;
               cout<<coins;
               }
```

Comment: 1) What did you do? 2) What did you expect to happen? 3) What actually happened?

Comment: What's your question?  If there's an error - how does it manifest?  Is there an error message?  If so post the text....

Comment: You need to make multiple changes in your code.  To begin with your `sort()` function won't work - how will it know what you mean when you say sort by *weight*.  Next, google `iterators`.  Iterators is what you need.

Comment: What the OP is asking is "how do I iterate a map", although it does need to be pointed out to him that map doesn't provide a `sort` member function, that `name` needs to be more than a single char, he's going to run into the usual problems using `cin >>`, and so on. Outlook: grim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot sort a `map`. The elements are already sorted in an
order defined by the key of each element.

If it is *guaranteed* that every piece will have a unique weight,
none the same as any other,
then you can use `weight` instead of `name` as your key
in a map of type `std::map<int,char>`.
Then simply iterating through the map will give you the elements
in order of increasing weight.

But if you do that
and if it ever happens that someone specifies two pieces that have
the same weight in the input to your program, one of the pieces
will be lost and will not appear at all in the output list.

For the reason just mentioned, using a `map` this way has a bad
"code smell" and I would be reluctant to use it in real life.
I would also be hesitant to give this as an answer to an
exercise in a programming course.

If you use `multimap` instead of `map`, however, you can have
multiple elements with the same key, still sorted according to the
order of their keys.
That seems like a much better idea.

Answer (score 0):

No need to sort . Only list needs to be sorted . Maps by default keep the data in sorted format